Can someone help me identify the issue with my auto login script?
I'm using python to automatically open a web page of an industrial camera to try to log into it for viewing. I found the example code online, but I can't get it to work for some unknown reason. Here is the python code:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
# import yaml

# conf = yaml.load(open('loginDetails.yml'))
# myLogin = conf['camera_user']['username']
# myPassword = conf['camera_user']['password']
myLogin = "operator"
myPassword = ""


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def login(url,usernameId, username, passwordId, password, submit_buttonId):
   driver.get(url)
   driver.find_element(usernameId).send_keys(username)
   driver.find_element(passwordId).send_keys(password)
   driver.find_element(submit_buttonId).click()

login("http://192.168.0.60/pages/hmi/", "dc608255-0d87-4f6e-9115-62d8621f104c", myLogin, "03b9beea-df2a-4738-a3a9-d2d4ec1c5517", myPassword, "75ec946e-6c5d-4e6c-8429-75161a1cc83b")

It does open chrome and navigates to the page as expected, but after the delay it just closes the window. Here is also the stack trace from trying to run it:
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60309BA4C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60307B983]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF603047628]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF603048791]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6034EA00D+3161901]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF60353E060+3506048]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF60353400D+3465005]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6032B0EEB+830987]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60316467F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6031609D4]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF603160B6D]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF603150149]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFE53BB7374+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFE5483CC91+33]

PS C:\Users\pjw56q> & C:/Users/pjw56q/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe d:/cameralogin/WebsitesLoginAutomation.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49281/devtools/browser/5c9bc2ed-a98a-43e6-99fe-e2fb16d04ee9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\cameralogin\WebsitesLoginAutomation.py", line 21, in <module>
    login("http://192.168.0.60/pages/hmi/", "UserTextBox", myLogin, "PasswordTextBox", myPassword, "LoginButton")
  File "d:\cameralogin\WebsitesLoginAutomation.py", line 17, in login
    driver.find_element(usernameId).send_keys(username)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pjw56q\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 766, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pjw56q\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 380, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\pjw56q\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator
  (Session info: chrome=130.0.6723.70)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6034C38A5+3004357]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF603159970]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60300582A]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF603055945]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF603055E7C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60309EC27]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60307BC1F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60309BA4C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60307B983]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF603047628]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF603048791]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6034EA00D+3161901]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF60353E060+3506048]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF60353400D+3465005]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6032B0EEB+830987]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60316467F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6031609D4]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF603160B6D]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF603150149]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFE53BB7374+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFE5483CC91+33]

I tried using different elements from the html for the three items I'm looking for, but that didn't work either. What's in the code above are the ids of the items, but I also tried using just their name.

driver.find_element(usernameId).send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(passwordId).send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(submit_buttonId).click()

Above code is incorrect. You need to specify the type of locator you want to use after using .find_element().
Assuming you intend to use the ID attribute of the element and assuming the ID you provided as an argument to the login() method is accurate. See the code below:
driver.find_element(By.ID, usernameId).send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.ID, passwordId).send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.ID, submit_buttonId).click()

Import required:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


Thank you! This helped a lot.
Now I am facing another problem. How do you open a new window with selenium + python? When I loop through each of the URLs I want to open, it just does it all in the same tab. I'd prefer a new window so I can arrange them and see them simultaneously.

Glad it helped. What should I do when someone answers my question?. Regarding your second question, I suggest creating a new question with all the details and reproducible steps. This way you will get help from wider community members.
